# mysql checking if a column value is in a string

Tags: mysql

I need to find in MySQL when a column value is part of a string.  Really I'm trying to input a folder path like "/folder1/folder2/" and change a value on all of its parent folders.

This is what I have which isn't working:

```
UPDATE content_folders SET size = size+47654765 WHERE path% LIKE "/folder1/folder2/"
```

So for example with "/folder1/folder2/", I would need to operate on any row where the column path is "/" or "/folder1".

I also tried this to no avail:

```
mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE content_folders SET size = size+".filesize("content/$id")." WHERE concat(path,'%') LIKE '".$path."'")
```

Comment: can you tell your current path value inside your database that you want to compare?

Comment: I think `path% LIKE "/folder1/folder2/"` is meant to be `path LIKE "/folder1/folder2/%"`

Comment: hjpotter - No it's not, that would operate on all sub directories, I need all parent directories.

Comment: Your table schema please?

Comment: What for?  There's just the size column (int(11)) and the path column (varchar).  I need to select every row that has a path column whose value is contained within the string I input.

Answer (score 0):

When using the LIKE operator, you use the % wildcard in the string portion of the query, not as part of the field name.

So

```
UPDATE content_folders SET size = size+47654765 WHERE path% LIKE "/folder1/folder2/"
```

should be

```
UPDATE content_folders SET size = size+47654765 WHERE path LIKE "/folder1/folder2/%"
```

EDIT:

I misread the original question.

You can select parent directories with something like:

```
UPDATE content_folders SET size = size+47654765 WHERE INSTR("/folder1/folder2/", path) = 1 AND path != "/folder1/folder2/";
```

Comment: That would perform an operation on all subdirectories (longer paths), not parent directories (shorter paths).  That's why this is annoying, I need basically the opposite of a typical LIKE operator.  Like some sort of substring operator or something.

Comment: My apologies for misreading the original intent.  Please see if the edit works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
UPDATE content_folders SET size = size+4674567 WHERE instr("/folder1/folder2/",path)
```

Comment: If you had a directory /folder2/, this will be updated as well, so this isn't working strictly on parent directories.  If you look at the edit I had posted earlier below, the INSTR result is compared to 1 to ensure the path starts at the beginning.